# Electronic circuit

Tags: relay, delay

I am planing make a water pump circuit connected with a switch and when i press the switch the water pump should start pumping water for six seconds (x seconds) and then stop itself and whenever i press the button same should happen so please help.

Comment: Is ita allowed to require  the client to hold the button for six seconds?

Comment: So what is your question? Show us how far you've got with your design otherwise it looks like you're looking for a free design service.

Comment: Questions here are expected to be on more of a professional level, asking for a free design is unprofessional. First you read the rules http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask then you do research, come up with a design and then ask specific answerable questions. How are you going to fix a design if you don't understand how it works?

Comment: Is that really the best title you could dream up?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a 555 timer configured in [monostable mode](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/operating-modes.html).  That's probably the cheapest option.  However, microcontrollers are pretty cheap now.  It might be easier to buy an Arduino and a motor driver shield (or something to drive the pump) and then program the Arduino to wait for 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion on a newsgroup a long time ago in a place far away that resulted in the following circuit. You specified a period of \$6\$ seconds and I've tailored the circuit to fit it. However, the topology is not my work. It's just something I remember from reading the work of others.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzsy12.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_3\$ is a little low for 6 seconds, but not by much. You can adjust \$C_1\$ and \$R_3\$ to get you where you need to be. \$SW_1\$ is assumed to be a momentary push button that initiates the timed interval. It can be pressed again after the interval is over.

This timed switching circuit is conceptual, only. I don't know what your pump requires for its voltage source (could be AC, could be DC, could be 12V, could be 100V.) And the above circuit is nice with \$12V\$ as its rail. But you can replace your load in the diagram with a relay (with an associated flyback diode) and use the relay to drive whatever you want, I suppose.